# Unable to get products that are both In-Stock and Out-of-Stock WC_Product_Query Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filtering

I'm using new WC_Product_Query to get products for a stock report but so far I'm only able to set In-stock or Out-of-Stock in the query.

How do I go about setting the query to get all products regardless of stock status or set it to just grab In-stock and Out-of-Stock products as we don't use backorders?

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'return' => 'ids',
                        'category' => $club_cat,
                        'limit' => -1,
                    ) );
```

Its probably worth mentioning that if i use `'stock_status' => 'outofstock',` I don't get any products returned and `'stock_status' => 'instock',` only returns products that are in stock.

I'm not sure if it's relevant to this but we use a mix of simple and variable products some are stock managed at the product level and others stock managed 
at the variation level.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: that's strange as I get nothing, just to confirm did you test on a variable product with the variation stock set to zero? Does it make a difference that I have multiple variations and only one is out of stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just perfectly. I have tested this query:

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    //'return' => 'ids',
    'limit' => -1,
    'stock_status' => 'outofstock',
) );
```

> **Important note:** The **`WC_Product_Query` doesn't loop Product variations**, as it's made for "product" post type only.

So **you should better use a `WP_Query`** instead even if database changes are planed in future WooCommerce versions and that will not happen for a while anyways. `WC_Product_Query` and `WC_Order_Query` still need very big enhancements as they are very limited for instance.

Comment: Thanks, ill give wp_query a go